# android: How to change the state of some view in an item of a listview independly of the state of the item?

Tags: android, listview, selector

I want to change the state of an ImageView in the items of a listview,without being affected by the state of the parent item. but I failed to get it? I'd be really appreciate for  your kind responses! and my code is just like the following !

first part of the items' layout in the listview :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_new_folder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_edit_icon" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/iv_delete_folder"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        /> 

second the drawable of the imageview 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/iv_delete_p"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/iv_delete_n"/>
</selector>
```

when I click the item while not the image itself ,I find that the drawable is being pressed
! any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the attribute: `android:duplicateParentState="true/false"`

When this attribute is set to true, the view gets its drawable state (focused, pressed, etc.) from its direct parent rather than from itself

Comment: thanks you very much,Martijin Mierloo. However  your answer  can not solve the problem,I still find that the image be in pressed state ,when I press the item which involve it,no matter set the duplicateParentSate true or false